# Mockito Stub unexpected behaviour

Tags: java, mockito

I know that I should not use Mockito this way, but I can't understand why this **Mockito** code :

```
public class Demo {

    public static void main(String... args){
        Foo foo = Mockito.mock(Foo.class);
        Mockito.doReturn(-1).when(foo);
        System.out.println(foo.myMethod("a"));
        System.out.println(foo.myMethod("a"));
    }

    public interface Foo{
        int myMethod(Object o);
    }
}
```

Gives this result :

```
0
-1
```

Instead of :

```
0
0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Argument type safety is missing with `doReturn()`.
From the [`Mockito.doReturn()` javadoc](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.21.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#doReturn-java.lang.Object-) (emphasis is not mine) :

> Use `doReturn()` in those rare occasions when you cannot use
>   `when(Object)`.
>
> **Beware that Mockito.when(Object) is always recommended for stubbing
>   because it is argument type-safe and more readable** (especially when
>   stubbing consecutive calls).

You actually don't use `when()` as you have to and so you get a weird result as it is permissive.

You want to stub the returned value of Mock :

```
Mockito.doReturn(-1).when(foo).myMethod(Mockito.any());
```

you don't want to stub the mock itself :

```
Mockito.doReturn(-1).when(foo);
```

Which makes no sense : why referencing `foo` should return something ?

Or better use `Mockito.when()` that is not as much as permissive :

```
Mockito.when(foo).thenReturn(-1); // same oddity will not compile
Mockito.when(foo.myMethod(any())).thenReturn(-1); // but it will compile
```

Comment: I know the correct way of writing it, I just made a type while writing my tests and I'm trying to understand (just for curiosity) this strange behaviour

Comment: because `doReturn()` is more permissive. Personally I really avoid that. I updated